# A function that is not a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still new to coding and I'm trying to make a cookie clicker type game. I get

> upgradecursor is not a function

when I run it on Chrome. I don't really understand the problem as I have a function called `upgradecursor`.
Pls help! :(

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Test </title>
 <script>
 //List of variables
 var cookie = 0;
 var cursor = 1;
 var cursorupgradecost = 10;

function addcookie(){
    var textField = document.getElementById( "textField" );
    var currentValue = parseInt(textField.value);
 cookie = cookie + cursor;
 // Add one
    currentValue = currentValue + cursor;

    // Put it back with the new +1'd value
    textField.value = currentValue;}

function upgradecursor(){
 var textField = document.getElementById( "textField" );
    var currentValue = parseInt(textField.value);
 cookie = cookie - cursorupgradecost; 
 // Minus one
    currentValue = currentValue - cursorupgradecost;

    // Put it back with the new -10'd value
    textField.value = currentValue;
 
 //change the cost of the upgrade
 cursorupgradecost = cursorupgradecost * 1.5;
 
 //Upgrade the cursor
 cursor = cursor + 1;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
if (cursorupgradecost > cookie){
upgradecursor = false;}
else{
upgradecursor = true;}
</script>

<button type ="button" onClick = "upgradecursor()"/>Upgrade Cursor </button>
<input type="text" value="0" disabled name="lvl">
 <br>
 <button type="button" onClick="addcookie()"/>Add Cookie</button>
 <input type="button" value="Cookies" disabled name="clicker"> 

<input type="text" value="0" id="textField" readonly/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the script tag inside the body, you are setting upgradecursor to true or false. At that point, it is no longer a function. It is now a boolean.

Answer (score 6):

You are overwriting upgradecursor with a global variable after you include the JavaScript.

```
<script>
if (cursorupgradecost > cookie) {
    upgradecursor = false;
} else {
    upgradecursor = true;
}
</script>
```

This is the offending code. You need to rename this variable to something else to avoid overwriting the function.

Additionally, you should **definitely avoid declaring global variables like this** and look at making your code more encapsulated/modular.

--

**Update based on your objective**: If you want to only upgrade the cursor given a certain use case, then it might be useful to have a specific click handler that will run this check inside itself before calling upgradecursor. For example: -

```
function onCursorClick() {
    if (cursorCost > cookie) {
        // do something
    } else {
        upgradeCursor();
    }
}
```

Notice how I have used camel casing to declare my functions and variables? Make sure you update your variable declarations to match my casing. This is common practice. You can read more on coding conventions here: [W3Schools JavaScript Style Guide](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)

I'd like to point out listeners should be attached via JavaScript (see [DOM Event Listeners](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)), but make sure you update the click handler to match our update, like so: -

```
<button type="button" onClick="onCursorClick()"/>Upgrade Cursor</button>
```

Comment: Thank You!!! But uhh i wanted to disable the function upgradecursor if var cursorupgradecost is more than var cookie..

Comment: @ChromeEagle I have updated my answer with a recommended approach for what you're trying to achieve. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```
if (cursorupgradecost > cookie){
upgradecursor = false;}
else{
upgradecursor = true;}
```

So while you started out by defining `upgradecursor` as a function, you overwrote it with a boolean before you ever called it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<script>
if (cursorupgradecost > cookie){
upgradecursor = false;}
else{
upgradecursor = true;}
</script>
```

What on earth is that supposed to even do?

Remove it and it should work.